# getting an issue while archiving opentok audio/video chat

Tags: java, android, apache, build.gradle, opentok

I am trying to configure audio/video chat and archive audio/video chat with OpenTok API. I have successfully configure audio/video chat with OpenTok but unable to perform archive.

Getting following issue:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.class

This is my library:

[image]

Following are my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    //compile project(':androidConferenceWebRTC')
    compile project(':countryPicker')
    compile project(':customEmoji')
    compile project(':sugar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.2.3@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.3.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.5'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.20.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.2'
    compile 'com.splitwise:tokenautocomplete:1.3.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    //compile files('libs/opentok-android-sdk.jar')
    compile 'com.tokbox:opentok-server-sdk:2.3.2'
    //compile files('libs/opentok-server-sdk-2.3.2-javadoc.jar')
}
```

This is my log:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace:**

```
compile 'com.tokbox:opentok-server-sdk:2.3.2'
```

**With:**

```
compile group: 'com.tokbox', name: 'opentok-server-sdk', version: '2.2.0'
```

and Rebuild. This Should Solve your problem.

**Also, add this in your build.gradle file, if you have not already added them.**

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'        
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
```

I hope you have this already in your build.gradle, if not than include it too

```
        **multiDexEnabled true**
```

And `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in Dependencies.

Comment: after trying your solution, previous issue has been resolve but geeting new issue:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Base64Variant.class

here is my [buildgradle](http://paste.ofcode.org/LsaGSZggip3QGeRAAneRP7)

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/Base64Variant.class

Comment: I have already added those lines, Please check my build.gradle from abce comment

Comment: The Error Means that ,fasterxml.jackson.core jar in included twice in the build process. Just Check where this dependency is included than either remove it manually or use 'exclude' in your build file.

Comment: one by one remove the dependencies from your build.gradle file, target the dependencies which look suspicious, if error is not replicated than that is your target jar. If the jar is required by your project and you just wish to remove duplicate dependency, than use something like eg: compile ('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-ormlite:1.4.14') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
}